# Since the last Xcode update I can't work with images

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is the basic code I use to add an image named "Background.png" to an UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Since the last Xcode update the resource can't be loaded.

I tried running on an iPhone 6 - iOS 10.3 and the Simulator - iOS 11.0

For some reason even though the iOS deployment target is version 10.3 the simulator runs on iOS 11.0

The image is there, in the same folder as the project named: "Background.png"

I've been doing the same thing for years and now it has stoped working.

Anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: You don't actual state what the specific problem is. Are you trying to say that `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];` is returning `nil`?

Comment: The image doesn't display. Only the background color of the UIImageView appears as if there is no image at all. If I set imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; then I see only a red screen and nothing else.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question (thought it does hint at the answer). Most likely `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];` is returning `nil` which means your `Background.png` image is not in your app's bundle.

Comment: I tested it and the image is nil. Although I have added the image to the app bundle the same way I've been doing it for years.

Comment: Make sure the image is still selected for your target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to utilize the purpose of `Assets.xcassets`. Put your assets there and you can easily use your images. Note that you do not have to put the image's file extension. It's easy, like so:

```
UIImage *markerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:markerImage];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

I have an image in my `Assets.xcassets` named **marker**.

Edit: this is tested, I made an Objective-c project just for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved it as follow:

Simply Select your image, then check the box linked to your projet name in "Target Membership" (on the Right Window)

is it working ?
There is a Screenshot if needed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTOGJ.png

Comment: I followed your answer and the image is still nil.